# iPhone retina display with kobold2d

Tags: kobold2d

I recently upgraded to an iPhone retina display i.e., iPhone 5 and I am executing sample parallax background images; these images are positioned adjacent to each other in order to achieve endless scrolling... on the retina display i am witnessing a gap between the images and i am not seeing this gap when executing on the iPhone 4.  I read somewhere that KOBOLD 2.0.4 resolves this issue but it's unclear if i'm missing some instructions in the code to achieve this.  Also, i am using the templates provided by KOBOLD 2.0.4.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you are repositioning images once they are off the screen to achieve the endless effect you could be using images fitting iPhone 4 screen, and repositioning them once their position is outside the screen. That would result in a gap till the image is fully out of the screen on left end(or right).
If this is your case, there are 2 ways to fix it

1. Use 3 images in a row instead of 2, and position the image leaving the screen behind the last one.
2. Make iPhone 5 screen size background images.